# character encoding for TrueType format 0 cmap tables?

Tags: truetype

The [TrueType Reference Manual](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6cmap.html) explains that "cmap subtable format 0" maps 8-bit character codes to glyph index values.  Which encoding is used for these character codes?  Are these the first 256 unicode characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmap subtable format is semi-orthogonal to the encoding. As the TT Ref Manual explains (or, I think, a bit more clearly in the [OpenType spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap)), there are structs ("EncodingRecord" in the OT spec, "subtables" in the TT Ref Manual) that specify a platformID and encodingID. I say "semi" orthogonal since certain formats can be used only with certain platforms/encodings.

In practice, format 0 is only used for platform 1, Macintosh, or for platform 3 encoding 0, "Windows symbol". The Macintosh platform uses only legacy 8-bit encodings defined in older Mac platforms.

When creating new fonts, format 0 should only be used for "Windows symbol" fonts, and even that is no longer best practice (the non-standard characters can be represented using Unicode private-use area code points).

Comment: I'm still not clear about "legacy 8-bit encodings defined in older Mac platforms". If I have platformID=1 (Macintosh), encodingID=0, format=0, how do I know which character encoding is used?

Comment: Apple's doc on the 'cmap' table states, "Macintosh encoding
When the platformID is 1 (Macintosh), the platformSpecificID is a QuickDraw script code. See the 'name' table documentation for a list of these." So, go to the 'name' table page, https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html, and it will tell you that platform 1 encoding 0 is "Roman". I don't know if Apple still documents that encoding, but you can find documentation elsewhere, such as wikipedia.